# Windows Identify monitor feature, can you invoke it?

Tags: winapi

When you go into screen resolution control panel in windows 7 the monitors are listed with numbers and there is an identify button that causes the ID's to show up on both displays.

Is there a way to get at this via the win32 API?

Comment: It's something you can implement yourself. The numbers that show up are just windows and you make them the same way you make any window: with `RegisterClassEx()` and `CreateWindowEx()`. The number shapes can be set by the `SetWindowRgn()` function. The settings dialog isn't doing anything special in particular.

Comment: I really want to use the same numbers as windows. I haven't been able to find a method of quering for them and they don't seem to match up with anything in WMI

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? What have you tried, where are you stuck?